# Java - How to get element in list without declaring it?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to do something very simple:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println({"Beäbuä","Shun", "Kalle", "Pelle","Jorpi","Lelle","Cilla", "Basse","Sebbe","Nisse","Lasse","Paow<3"}[1])
    }
}
```

This generates 29 errors, saying various things.

What is the problem here? Why can't I get the 1 element of an array this way?

APPLICATION:

I was writing a class with a second constructor generating random names for the original constructor. The list above is a list of names. My problem was that the random generation of names had to be done in the `this(inputarg1, inputarg2)` line, since this line has to come first in the second constructor.

Comment: Good question : but what is the application of it ?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the application to the end of the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler doesnt know the type of the array so this needs to be defined explicitly

```
System.out.println
     (new String[] {"Beäbuä","Shun", "Kalle", "Pelle","Jorpi","Lelle","Cilla", "Basse","Sebbe","Nisse","Lasse","Paow<3"}[1]);
```